# como usar o filter_input NO $_POST

Tags: php

Bom uso o `filter_input` assim:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome_input', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Queria saber como faço pata usar ele na `$_POST` para todos os input, sem informar o nome.

Answer (score 1):

Basta obter todos os nomes dos campos com a função [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) e iterar sobre os mesmos:

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $var)
{
    $filtered[$var] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $var, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
```

Desta forma, `$filtered` possuirá todos os valores de `$_POST` após passar pelo filtro.

Você pode, alternativamente, utilizar a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php):

```
$filtered = array_map(function ($var) {
    return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $var, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}, $_POST);
```

Comment: Mesmo assim o meu netbeans fica pedido para eu usar o filter no `$_POST`. Segue foto para vc entende melhor. http://i.imgur.com/a6ZLZbv.png